# Principle of proof of infinitesimal sequence

Tags: analysis

I have such tasks:

Prove by definition that a sequence ($a_n$) is infinitely small if:

1) $a_n=\frac{3}{n}$

2) $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$

3) $a_n=\frac{1}{2n-1}$

4) $a_n=\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}+1}$

Tell me the sources for which I can learn to solve such tasks

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, you have to prove that $\exists n_{\varepsilon}$ such that $|a_{n}-0|<\varepsilon$ $\forall n>n_{\varepsilon}$.

1) $\frac{3}{n}<\varepsilon\iff  3<\varepsilon n$.

$\mathbb{R}$ is archimedean, so exists $n_{\varepsilon}$ such that $3<\varepsilon n_{\varepsilon}$.
It's easy to prove that the sequence is strictly decreasing, and that finishes the proof.

2) It's quite the same: $|a_{n}-0|<\varepsilon \iff 1<\varepsilon \sqrt[3]{n} \iff 1<\varepsilon^{3} n$, so you can complete the proof in the same way as above.

3) $2n-1>n$, so you can repeat the same strategy used in the first case

4) You can reason as in the second case

I think you can learn how to solve exercise like this in any analysis 1 book you like.